# how add CDATA in the middle of a soap request transformation in mule?

Tags: soap, mule, cdata, dataweave, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to create a transformation with dataweave in mule.

The request I must create with a transformation is:

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <xsd:getDecision>
      <xsd:request>
          <![CDATA[
            <Request xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17 http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-core-v3-schema-wd-17.xsd" ReturnPolicyIdList="false" CombinedDecision="false" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
              <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
                <Attribute IncludeInResult="false" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Julius Hibbert</AttributeValue>
                </Attribute>
                <Attribute IncludeInResult="false" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:conformance-test:age">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">45</AttributeValue>
                </Attribute>
              </Attributes>
            </Request>
          ]]>
      </xsd:request>
    </xsd:getDecision>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

And my transformation is:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%namespace xsd http://org.apache.axis2/xsd
%namespace xsi http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
---
{
  xsd#getDecision: {
    xsd#request: { 
      Request @( 
        xsi#schemaLocation: "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17 http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-core-v3-schema-wd-17.xsd",
        ReturnPolicyIdList: "false",
        CombinedDecision: "false",
        xmlns: "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17",
        xsi: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"): {
          Attributes @(
            Category: "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"): {
              Attribute @(
                IncludeInResult: "false",
                AttributeId: "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id"): {
                  AttributeValue @(
                    DataType: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"): "Julius Hibbert"
                },
              Attribute @(
                IncludeInResult: "false",
                AttributeId: "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:conformance-test:age"): {
                  AttributeValue @(
                    DataType: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"): 45
                } 
            }
        }
    } 
  } 
}
```

My problem is that I must put CDATA inside the Request tag, 
I've checked this link:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-formats#custom-types-2

But It seems like it doesn't support the function as :cdata in a block
Something like this:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%namespace xsd http://org.apache.axis2/xsd
%namespace xsi http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
---
{
  xsd#getDecision: {
    xsd#request: { 
      Request @( 
         ........
        } **as :cdata**
    } 
  } 
}
```

So, how can I insert this CDATA in the middle of the transformation as a block or maybe there is a better way to do that.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Have you tried to perform this in two DW transformations? I might look at transforming your _inner_ xml in one DW, store that as a string in a flowVar, then reference that flowVar as :cdata. (Haven't tried it myself though)

Comment: Hi @ChadGorshing , thanks for your response.
I tried what you mentioned, but it didn't work because the funcion :cdata only works with strings and my first transformation throw an xml. Now I'm researching how can convert an xml object to string and in this way use :cdata.